# While loop condition not working

Tags: c++, while-loop, text-based

Hey basically i want both the player and the wolves to attack each other until one another are dead.  But the while loop is infinite so obviously the condition is not met.  But i cant see where i am going wrong with this if ( choice1 == 1) // if statement is used throughout the game to allow the user to interact through the game with choices.

```
while((Status.health != 0) && (Wolves.health != 0) )
        {
        int playerAttack = Status.strength + hitPoints() +  Rock.attack;
        cout<< "This is the player attack" << playerAttack;
        Wolves.health = Wolves.health - playerAttack;
        cout << "This is the wolves health" << Wolves.health;
        if (Wolves.health <= 0)
        {
            cout << "\nThe wolves are dead\n ";
        }
        int wolfAttack = Wolves.attack + hitPoints();
        Status.health - wolfAttack;
        if(Status.health <= 0)
        {
            gameOver();
        }// print out of object health.
        }
```

Can anybody help ?

Comment: can health ever be LESS THAN 0?

Comment: Wel i never said if(health< 0) if thats what you mean

Comment: Havee you tried debugging your code?

Comment: Well, your while condition only checks to make sure that both values are NOT zero.  Most likely you are decreasing health below 0 and thus the while condition is still true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, i think the health was not exact 0 - because your condition looks only for != 0
it should be bigger than 0

while((Status.health > 0) && (Wolves.health > 0))
...

edit: also the missing = John Dibling found first

Comment: Oh i get it now.  Because the value was going less that zero it wasnt doing the while condition.

Answer (score 3):

Compare:

```
Wolves.health = Wolves.health - playerAttack;
```

vs

```
Status.health - wolfAttack;
```

Notice any difference?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that this is correct:

```
Status.health - wolfAttack;
```

This actually is a no-operation.  Perhaps you meant:

```
Status.health -= wolfAttack;
```

Answer (score 2):

in computer some of numbers cannot be represented for example 0.1, so if you calculate 1 - (0.1 * 10) its result not equal to zero. You checked only !=0 and ==0 condition. Try this:

> =0 or <=0 also if your "health" variable is integer you give a error tolerance such as:
>   =(0.5) or <=(0.5) etc...

Answer (score 1):

Most likely both values are never zero. That sounds likely, because you yourself use the `<=` condition.

Answer (score 1):

I think your are getting negative values, I recomend to use

```
while((Status.health > 0) && (Wolves.health > 0) )
```